# View profile on mobile site

Tags: support, mobile-web

Is there any other button on the Stack Overflow mobile site which will take me to my profile page? I find the current profile button really small to try and hit with my finger.

It's about 20px high, compared to nearly 40px for the logo and the expand button:

[image: Profile photo]

I *could* bookmark it, but just in case there's something I'm missing.